# Java/Spring.. Is it possible to have dynamic scheduling per object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Have a Java/Spring app.  Within the app, users are able to create a `thing` and either enable/disable it.  That's just a boolean flag on the object.

What I want to do is add a start/end datetimes to the object, where user can schedule when they want the `thing` to be enabled and disabled, and then it happen.

I've been looking at Spring's scheduling, but as far as I can tell, that's more for scheduling specific jobs to run at a time vs. setting a "schedule" on the object.

Am I just missing the capability to do what I want?

Answer (score -1):

The quartz scheduler can be used for this purpose.  You can create triggers at runtime based on start and end datetimes associated with your objects.  See http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0.